# html data scraping in python

Tags: python, django

I am getting the data in the html format. how to get the specific data from that format. The complete html is coming in the post request of the django. Now  I have to fetch the data in the between the tables tags in html. Tried beautifulSoup but is taking data from urls. Any possible way to get data between the tags in python .

python version:2.7

Comment: beautifulSoup will do the trick.

Comment: the problem is most likely not with BeautifulSoup but with how you were using it

Answer (score 1):

beautiful soup and requests.

requests to get the data then beautiful soup to read from tags 
eg.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) 
div_style = div.find('div')['style']
```

If the page is javascript based you may need to use selenium and webdriver with the browser of your choice. If its css based you may need cssutils to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

As @lxx said, BeautifulSoup+requests is a great way for doing it, I have used it myself and it works great.

I'd also recommend you to check [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

If you are dealing with a potentially big project, it will be a great investment (in time and code simplicity) for you to use [Xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) for querying the html code.